# New Close Dialog on SO - Nice, but Unexpected

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, close-reasons

I just noticed:

[image: New Close Dialog]

I think I like the new format better.

On the other hand, I either missed the discussion on this, or I missed the announcement. Kindly answer with the URL to what I missed.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5018/describing-close-reasons

Comment: @John: That's the reason list, not the new layout.

Comment: I thought you were talking to yourself until I saw that one of you was "Smithers" and the other "Saunders". Very similar though.

Comment: You'll never have that mistake with my name ...

Comment: Really a little curious about the reason for a *downvote* on *meta* on a *question* that's about the fact that a change wasn't announced. Downvoter: please explain. Anyone else: I can't imagine a reason, so please help me imagine.

Comment: @Kyle: There is always something to talk about with all my multiple personalities. No, they are no sock puppets!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *know* this was working right last night, but now it seems that the text entry field in the exact duplicate selection box is now running over the edge:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The flag menu got an overhaul, too. It looks nice, but I'm not sure why it was done. It also takes slightly longer to close, as you have to click your close reason, then click "Vote to Close" as opposed to just clicking the close reason directly.

I would have rather seen upgrades to the exact duplicate close menu to allow closing as an exact duplicate of [more than one question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7670/add-separate-field-for-duplicate-questions/7895#7895).

Comment: GREASEMONKEY TIME

Answer (score 1):

Huh, I thought it was just me. On the IE7 that I'm using at the moment, after selecting a reason the popup window gets really wide and I have to scroll to the right to see it all (and to find the "Vote to close" button).

Comment: Same happens for me with IE7.

Comment: we fixed this on IE7

Answer (score 1):

I hate the new menu.  When I'm using my laptop it drops below the bottom of my screen and I have to scroll to register my vote.  The thing is massive.

Answer (score 0):

I just got a 404 a little while ago, which means I must have hit when Jeff was deploying it.

I like it. It encourages me to get the 1,000 more rep I need to be able to use it!

Answer (score 0):

What I'd really like is for a second click on 'Close' to remove the menu (same as clicking 'Cancel').

Answer (score 0):

Yuck! I find the new dialog to be really intrusive and ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is the answer to "my fat fingers keep hitting the wrong close option"...

**I still wanna be able to change or retract my close votes**. But, every little bit helps...